# SQL nested select, simple issue

Tags: sql

I'm trying to retrieve the event ID and endDate from a list that includes multiple endDates for the same ID.  That step was easy enough using max() and grouping, but where I am struggling is then restricting those results to only those where the max end date has already passed.

I believe this requires the use of nested SQL, but I just can't get it to work.

Records:

```
eventID  | endDate
   1         05/01/2015
   1         05/01/2014
   1         05/01/2013
   2         05/01/2016
   3         07/01/2016
   4         05/01/2014
   4         05/01/2013
```

Desired results (where today = June 2015):

```
eventID  | endDate
   1         05/01/2015
   4         05/01/2014
```

This code gets me the list of all events and their max end date, and from this I need to get the ContentID and EndDate where the EndDate is before today.  I've tried adding a where statement to limit the date but that gets executed prior to the max(event.EndDate) which doesn't get me the results I need.

```
 select event.ContentID, max(event.EndDate) as EndDate
 from event
 group by event.ContentID
```

Any help would be much appreciated!

Comment: Which server do you use? sql-server? Oracle? MySQL?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use the having clause instead of where to filter based on aggregate formulas such as max():

```
SELECT event.ContentID
    ,max(event.EndDate) AS EndDate
FROM event
GROUP BY event.ContentID
HAVING max(event.EndDate) < getdate()
```

Answer (score 3):

On SQL-Server you could use this:

```
SELECT event.ContentID, max(event.EndDate) as EndDate
FROM event
GROUP BY event.ContentID
HAVING MAX(event.EndDate) <= GETDATE()
```

on MySQL:

```
SELECT event.ContentID, max(event.EndDate) as EndDate
FROM event
GROUP BY event.ContentID
HAVING MAX(event.EndDate) <= CURDATE()
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the first SQL as the from clause of the outer SQL, since the first SQL creates a table. So you can do:

```
SELECT 
   contentID,
   EndDate
FROM
(
   SELECT
      event.ContentID AS ContentID,
      max(event.EndDate) AS EndDate
   FROM
      event
   GROUP BY
      event.contentID
)
WHERE
   MONTH(event.EndDate) = 6 --where the enddate has a month of June (6)
```

Note: I wasn't able to test this exact code, but the idea should answer your question.

Comment: The other answers are more optimal; go with those.

Answer (score 0):

I came up with the following which seems to do the trick, but not sure this is the best approach?

```
 select content.ContentID, content.Title, b.EndDate
 from content
 inner join(
    select event.ContentID, max(event.EndDate) as EndDate
    from event
    group by event.ContentID
    ) as b on b.ContentID=content.ContentID
where b.EndDate< getdate()
```

Comment: Why would you use this rather than just using a HAVING clause?